# Overriding keyDown: in an NSTableView category disables arrow key handling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, nstableview, objective-c-category

I have an `NSTableView` and I have some issues with its default behavior.

If I've overridden the `keyDown:` method in a category as follows:

```
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super keyDown:event];
}
```

I can't change the row selection with the keyboard arrow keys anymore. Why is that?

Comment: where do you override that method in your view controller ?

Comment: No, in a category of NSTableView. I haven't written the category, but  the - (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)event method is overridden there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> in a category of NSTableView.

In a *category* of `NSTableView`, `super` refers to `NSTableView`'s superclass (`NSControl`), not to `NSTableView` as it would in a *subclass*. You're passing the event on to the `NSControl` version of `keyDown:`, which knows nothing about table views and can't handle the arrow keys the way you want.

If you override a method in a category, there's no way to call the original method. It's almost never a good idea to do this on framework classes (whose source is unavailable to you). Use a subclass.

Cf. [Using Super in an Objective C Category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405060/using-super-in-an-objective-c-category) and [Is calling super in a category the same as calling it in a subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168058/is-calling-super-in-a-category-the-same-as-calling-it-in-a-subclass)