# inherit from a subclass of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, uiview, subclass

I've added a functionality to UIView by extending drawRect.
This works great for a simple UIView, but the problem is that I want it to work also for UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView and every other component that inherits from UIView.

I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this. Can I make a subclass of UILabel (for example) that inherits from MyView instead of UIView?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a category of `UIView` and override drawRect function, so all subclasses of UIView, that call to `[super drawRect:...]` will use this category function, though you should be extremely cautious while doing this, since you override something very basic there. I did it at time with `UINavigationBar` when I would need to add a background picture there. But take into consideration that not all subclasses of `UIView` call `[super drawRect:...]`.

Comment: a category allows me only to override an implementation, not to extend it, meaning that I can't call [super drawRect:] inside my overridden method. I need to extend the basic functionality of drawRect, not override it.

Comment: According to WWDC 2011 session 123 "Improving The Stability of Your App" - you should never over-ride drewRect. The recommanded practice by Apple is to extend the UIView class

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405060/using-super-in-an-objective-c-category

Comment: @NavaCarmon, thanks, I read this question already but I think that method swizzling is such a hugh overkill for this case. Also, I don't really know how method swizzling affect performance, or whether or not apple even approve apps that use it. I hope there's a simpler way to do what I need.