# Accessing super-super-super class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have classes defined roughly like so:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property BOOL propA;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property BOOL propB;
@end

@interface ClassC : ClassB
@property BOOL propC;
@end

@interface ClassD : ClassC
@property BOOL propD;
@end
```

Now in my implementation file, I try the following:

```
@implementation ClassD

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _propD = NO;
        // Fails because _propC is private, so I can't see it:
        _propC = NO;
        // Works:
        super.propC = NO;
        // Fails, because property "super.super" not found
        super.super.propB = NO;
        super.super.super.propA = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

How can I set `propB` and `propA` in this case?

Comment: I'm not coding in Objc for awhile now, but why you don't use `self.propC` instead?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Of course, it seems so simple now :) I think maybe I tried that at one point and the auto-complete wasn't detecting it, so I assumed it wouldn't work. But I just tried it now and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have no access to instance variables of the superclass directly, but you have access to the setters. So you can do it simply like:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _propD = NO;
        self.propC = NO;
        self.propB = NO;
        self.propA = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP *really* wanted to traverse the super-super-super class hierarchy  (which **is not** the case as it turns out in the question) and **actually call** the method

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property BOOL propA;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property BOOL propA;
@end

@interface ClassC : ClassB
@property BOOL propA;
@end

@interface ClassD : ClassC
@property BOOL propA;
@end
```

this technically *can be done*, however is a bit cumbersome:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>
    ClassD* instance = [ClassD new];
    BOOL result;

    struct objc_super super = {
        .receiver = instance,
        .super_class = class_getSuperclass(instance.class)
    };

    BOOL (*objc_msgSendSuper_typed)(struct objc_super *, SEL) = (void *)&objc_msgSendSuper;
    //call super.propA - at this class hierarchy level obviously normal super.propA would suffice
    result = objc_msgSendSuper_typed(&super, @selector(propA));

    struct objc_super superSuper = {
        .receiver = instance,
        .super_class = class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(instance.class))
    };

    //call "super.super".propA
    result = objc_msgSendSuper_typed(&superSuper, @selector(propA));

    struct objc_super superSuperSuper = {
        .receiver = instance,
        .super_class = class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(instance.class)))
    };

    //call "super.super.super".propA
    result = objc_msgSendSuper_typed(&superSuperSuper, @selector(propA));
```

Slightly more complicated variant of this with args covered also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541211/5329717).

Answer (score 0):

> // Fails, because property "super.super" not found

That's because `super` isn't a property, but rather a keyword, like `self`.